# BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED does not fire upon user action?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I want to keep track of the subscription status of the active billing agreements.

Now I thought webhooks would be handy for this.

I have a listener for `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED` which is described as

> This event is triggered when a billing subscription is cancelled.

Now when a user goes to his paypal account and cancels the subscription, nothing gets fired. Only if I use the REST API to cancel the subscription, this hook fires. Where's the point in this? When I do an API call I get instant response that a subscription was cancelled or not, why would sb need an additional webhook for that?

The only useful application for this would be to be in track of what a user does with his paypal account.
Now my question is: is this sandbox behaviour? Does the hook fire in "real world" when a user cancels the subscription/agreement through paypal directly?

Comment: 6 years on, I am having this exact same issue (and the mind baffles at why there wouldn't be a simple REST webhook firing when a user cancels a subscription?!). I have spoken to Paypal support and asked why the IPN simulator doesn't have a "Subscription Cancellation" event (they had no answer, just "you are right, there isn't one" lol) ... so this appears to be a nightmare to simply keep track (on your own app) whether a user is still subscribed/not ...

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966268/paypal-webhook-when-subscription-ends-expires-not-fired

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the IPN (Instant Payment Notification) message service for handling user triggered Subscription cancels via the PayPal Dashboard.

You can find a list of Recurring Payment notifications which are sent through the IPN [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/#recurring-payments-notifications).

Also, you will quickly find out that their support for the IPN message service is very limited when testing code in development (they have an [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/), but it doesn't support Recurring notifications). So you will have to go through their [variable documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB080EYK) to see how best to implement the logic in your application.

Comment: Now web hook working well? or still have same issue, Can you please help me?

Comment: Does this work in sandbox environment? I am actually surprised this question doesn't have more views/upvotes as I can't imagine how many developers must be trying to do this same thing (keeping track of a subscription cancellation)

Comment: @gvanto Yes, when I worked on this it was functional in a sandbox environment.