# Paypal webhook when subscription ends/expires not fired

Tags: paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

There are several webhooks for PayPal, I enabled the following:

- Billing subscription activated
- Billing subscription cancelled
- Billing subscription created
- Billing subscription expired
- Billing subscription payment failed
- Billing subscription re-activated
- Billing subscription suspended
- Billing subscription updated

While I receive: cancelled, created, activated, payment failed events and so on - I do not receive an event when the payment expires. However the subscription in my sandbox business account is clearly marked as expired after the period is over.
Does PayPal only send webhooks when someone does something actively and not when the time of the period is over?
I have just a simple PHP-Script for testing purpose and it just logs all requests together with the payload.
The `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.EXPIRED` never appears in the logs.

So my question is: did I get it wrong or do I need a custom cronjob that checks for the expiration date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using trial periods, the only event you need to listen for is PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED

None of the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.* events are of any particular utility

Cron or whichever scheduler or on-demand checking you wish to use should handle profiles that do not receive new PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED events by a desired date.

---

Also, is worth noting that if you wish to detect when a user cancels their subscription via PP dashboard, or when the same subscription is cancelled by an admin in the dashboard - you can't use webhooks for this. The BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED is not triggered from dashboard cancellations and you have no way to detect this action. You can poll subscriptions with a GET API call to see if they are still active. But the simplest solution is as above: only track PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED and don't concern yourself with whether the subscription is active in PayPal or not; use your own "is it active?" status based on whether payments are received on time or not.

Comment: Okay, so PayPal actually doesn't provide a clear way to tell me when the subscription is expired despite those hooks seem to exist but they do nothing?

Comment: to state "None of the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.* events are of any particular utility" in here and get a checkmark  + upvote -> i can't understand. for sure they provide utility

Comment: No, they do not. Most subscription integrations should not bother doing anything at all with those events.

Comment: I found myself missing some `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED` notifications. They work fine 99% or even 99.99% of all cases but every blue moon I get asked why a subscription is not marked as cancelled. When I take a look there is no notification of cancellation. So though they might provide some utility they are not 100% reliable in my case and I had to work around the (seemingly random) edge cases.

Comment: Not a useful event in general since a subscription not being cancelled does not mean it will stay that way nor that the next payment will be successful. So ignoring the cancelled event, the logic is the same.